# Radio Button Method - HTML Accordion

Tags: html, css

I would like some assistance with my accordion code,

My idea is to get something like this:

The Radio Button Method adds a hidden radio input and a label tag to each accordion tab.

The logic is straightforward:

- when a user selects a tab, they essentially check the radio button associated with that tab.
- when a user clicks the next tab in the accordion, the next radio button is selected, and so on.
  Only one tab can be open at a time using this method.

I'd like some advice on how to incorporate this into my current accordion code.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input {
            display: none;
        }

        label {
            display: block;    
            padding: 8px 22px;
            margin: 0 0 1px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #6AAB95;
            border-radius: 3px;
            color: #FFF;
            transition: ease .5s;
            position: relative; /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
        }

        label:hover {
            background: #4E8774;
        }

        label::after {
            content: '+';
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 2px;
        }

        input:checked + label::after {
            content: '-';
            right: 14px;
            top: 3px;
        }

        .content {
            background: #E2E5F6;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
            margin: 0 0 1px 0;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        input + label + .collapse {
            display: none;
        }

        input:checked + label + .collapse {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="title1" />
    <label for="title1">Accordion 1</label>

    <div class="collapse">
        <p>Your content goes here inside this division with the class "content".</p>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="title2" />
    <label for="title2">Accordion 2</label>

    <div class="collapse">
        <p>Your content goes here inside this division with the class "content".</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to change the `CSS` (at least the part handling the accordion functionality) but you'd have to change a bit in your `HTML`.

To get the desired accordion effect where **only one tab can be open at a time** you should:

- use radio buttons instead of checkboxes (`input[type="radio"]`).
- And the important part is to give those radio buttons the **same name** (the attribute `name` must be the same for all the accordion component's radio buttons) in order to achieve the desired outcome.

Here's a a live demo:

```css
/** nothing changed on the CSS part, see the HTML part for the required changes */

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 22px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #6AAB95;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: ease .5s;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
}

label:hover {
  background: #4E8774;
}

label::after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
}

input:checked+label::after {
  content: '-';
  right: 14px;
  top: 3px;
}

.content {
  background: #E2E5F6;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input+label+.collapse {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label+.collapse {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- changed "type=checkbox" to "type=radio" -->
<!-- added the same "name" attribute value for all the radio buttons -->
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="title1" />
<label for="title1">Accordion 1</label>
<div class="collapse">
  <p>Your content goes here inside this division with the class "content".</p>
</div>
<!-- changed "type=checkbox" to "type=radio" -->
<!-- added the same "name" attribute value for all the radio buttons -->
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="title2" />
<label for="title2">Accordion 2</label>
<div class="collapse">
  <p>Your content goes here inside this division with the class "content".</p>
</div>
```

> **CAUTION:** Even though the radio buttons hack works as needed, there is no way you can close all the accordion items after interacting for the first time (you can have a closed accordion initially though).

Comment: Great answer. I have learned it the hard way tonight testing some time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Feels good to find out things on your own :) Out of interest after reading your hint at the bottom. Would you use this approach for huge website navs?

Comment: @Christian if my opinion matters, i honestly wouldn't use such technic/hack on any of the live website that am working on, I'd rather use some dedicated solutions for this specific problem, accordion, which most UI frameworks out there ship with built-in solutions (they mostly use JS for the functionality though not only CSS). I might also add, this hack has more drawbacks than positives, especially when it comes to accessibility. That's my humble opinion which should be taken with a bit of salt as some might find it acceptable and other may not (which i truly respect).

Comment: Thank you. ATM, we have such a select box solution in our big nav. Accessibility is important though. I was thinking about how to convert it, the radio button issue came in pretty handy to understand how our nav currently works and how to change the behavior. I wanted to tackle this anyway but I will also look for alternative approaches.

Comment: @Christian you might have some time playing with this hack before using it in production, at least you get some time to fully have an idea on whether it works per your requirements or not.

Comment: Production is using checkboxes :D

Comment: @Christian: have you considered using the [`<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details), which handles the accessibility inherently (providing keyboard, as well as mouse/touch, functionality)? ([Simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/or26t7qp/))

Comment: Thx @DavidThomas I will definitely look into this and consider it when doing updates.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this example using Sass that looks exactly like what you need: https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/dyJbqpd.

The example uses radio buttons, such as  `<input type="radio" id="title1" name="select"/>`. Because they have the same name, you can only select one at a time.

In your example, you have checkboxes like in this example at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp). Using checkboxes, you can tick any number of checkboxes at a time, therefore the current accordion behavior.

Here's a stripped-down version (converted to CSS):

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}
  
.tab-label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: #2c3e50;
    background: white;
}

input:checked ~ .tab-content {
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="rd1" name="rd">
  <label class="tab-label" for="rd1">Item 1</label>
  <div class="tab-content">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="rd2" name="rd">
  <label class="tab-label" for="rd2">Item 2</label>
  <div class="tab-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

I have slightly changed your code and added another div with overflow: hidden:

```css
/** nothing changed on the CSS part, see the HTML part for the required changes */

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 22px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #6AAB95;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: ease .5s;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
}

label:hover {
  background: #4E8774;
}

label::after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
}

input:checked+label::after {
  content: '-';
  right: 14px;
  top: 3px;
}

.content {
  background: #E2E5F6;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input+label+.collapse {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label+.collapse {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="title1" name="select"/>
  <label for="title1">Accordion 1</label>
  <div class="collapse">
      Your content goes here inside this division with the class "content".
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" id="title2" name="select" />
  <label for="title2">Accordion 2</label>

  <div class="collapse">
      Your content goes here inside this division with the class "content".
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hei Christian, This is exactly what I'm looking for. I am having trouble figuring out where to add the css part to get the desired effect.

Comment: Learned something new today. I have tested the example and compared it with the code I have found (took me some time). Updated my post.